# Different virus types of testing on a Windows VM

Tags: malware, antivirus, windows-10, virus-removal

I am a masters student in computer science, and I need to do a project with virtual machine (host and guest both are Windows 10). The project is:

> Describe and experiment different methods to clean up viruses in a desktop environment of your choice.
>
> This means that you need to infect a (virtual) system and then clean it up with tools and methods you find on the Internet. Use different viruses to experiment these.

After researching for days, the test viruses that I have already found, (mostly here) are almost the same type and dealing with them is quite simple; I have not found an answer yet for my specific question:

Where may I find test viruses with different types, such as the ones mentioned in the Wikipedia page?

1. Operations and functions
2. Stealth strategies
3. Vulnerabilities and infection vectors
4. Countermeasures

what I specifically need, is a set of test viruses with diverse functions, which I can test and verify their functions and then remove them on Virtual machine.

Comment: This question is similar to a question on reverseenineering SE. https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206/where-can-i-as-an-individual-get-malware-samples-to-analyze Maybe you find some helpful pointers over there as well :)

Comment: I'd suggest the obvious: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=malware&type=

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find any compex viruses to match your requirements, why don't you create some? Use leading malware creation programs and techniques by yourself! For example, you can use metasploit framework and many other tools to create a bunch of different well-know types of viruses, encode them, obfuscate them, pack them etc. Also, try to inject malicious code in legit applications. Creating a small fleet of custom viruses, using different techniques to trick anti-virus programs, will give you both better knowledge of malwares and far more superior results on your research.

Answer (score -1):

You may try test the malware sample from http://www.wicar.org/test-malware.html. They have few types of malware that you can test ranging from CVE-2014-6332 to CVE-2015-5119.

Comment: it is important to note that the tests are only for browser exploits and aren't actually downloadable ....